# Should I use a callback or introduce a public field to aid with unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, moq

I've seen adding public properties advocated in the [Art of Unit Testing](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Unit-Testing-Examples-NET/dp/1933988274) (by Roy Osherove) to help get at and setup awkward (or internal) collaborators/collaborations used by a SUT,  and *have* used this technique myself to good effect.  (Also I have seen a similar approach using an additional constructor instead)

Likewise, a testing isolation framework (such as [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)) can provide an alternative and using Moq a Callback can be used to help set up an awkward collaborator/collaboration.

The trade off's that I have experienced here are that:

Using a public field introduces additional items into the SUT, with slightly cleaner testing code

Versus

A SUT uncluttered by additional items to make it testable and slightly more clunky testing code (the callback code is not the prettiest).

In my situation and, owing to a constraint on what is a command AND should be a query - a query which could return stubbed data, there is no easy way to administer the collaboration in the SUT (**without** the aforementioned mechanisms)

A collaborator in the SUT updates an object passed by reference in a command, this looks lik: (repeated in code examples a little later)

```
  var warehouse = new Warehouse(); // internal to Order
  _repo.Load(warehouse); // Warehouse is filled by reference
```

EDIT:  I have contrived an example which has design problems - Warehouse and Order are overly intimate, an application service could be use to orchastrate interactions etc.  The Nub of the problem is that I have very little control over how the Warehouse gets populated.  I am using a framework which uses a command to hydrate an object by reference.  This IS the problem, I know, but unfortunately I am constrained by it.  So the real focus of this question is not about a redesign but purely which method, callback or public field would be preferable, if this is all we had to work with.

The  code examples below are both working examples using Moq and NUnit.
For the purposes of time I have omitted adding an application service to orchestrate the example use case ( which is basically fill an Order from a compliant Warehouse - based on Fowler's [Mocks aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) example ). Also both approaches take a classic approach to unit testing, asserting state as opposed to verifying behaviour and this isn't my intended focus of the question.

Before going on,  I *do* have a preference but I would be interested to see what other people suggest or prefer.

So firstly the public property approach, code and tests: (smarts in the use of the Func<>)

```
public class Order
{
    private readonly IWarehouseRepo _repo;
    public int Items { get; private set; }

    public Func<Warehouse> WarehouseBuilder { get; set; }

    public Order(IWarehouseRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void AddOrderItems(int numberOfItems)
    {
        var warehouse = WarehouseBuilder();
        _repo.Load(warehouse);
        warehouse.RemoveStock(numberOfItems);
        Items += numberOfItems;
    }
}

public class Warehouse
{
    public int Items { get; set; }

    public void RemoveStock(int numberOfItems)
    {
        Items -= numberOfItems;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Given_A_Warehouse_With_20_Items
{
    private Order _order;
    private Mock<IWarehouseRepo> _warehouseRepo;
    private Warehouse _warehouse;

    [SetUp]
    public void When_An_Order_Is_Placed()
    {
        _warehouseRepo = new Mock<IWarehouseRepo>();

        _warehouse = new Warehouse() { Items = 20 };

        _order = new Order(_warehouseRepo.Object);
        _order.WarehouseBuilder = () => _warehouse; 
        _order.AddOrderItems(5);

    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_The_Order_Now_Has_5_Items()
    {
        Assert.That(_order.Items, Is.EqualTo(5));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_The_Warehouse_Now_Has_15_Items()
    {
        Assert.That(_warehouse.Items, Is.EqualTo(15));
    }
}

public interface IWarehouseRepo
{
    void Load(Warehouse warehouse);
}
```

And secondly the callback approach, code and tests: (Smarts in the callback)

```
 public class Order
{
    private readonly IWarehouseRepo _repo;
    public int Items { get; private set; }

    public Order(IWarehouseRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void AddOrderItems(int numberOfItems)
    {
        var warehouse = new Warehouse();
        _repo.Load(warehouse);
        warehouse.RemoveStock(numberOfItems);
        Items += numberOfItems;
    }
}

public class Warehouse
{
    public int Items { get; set; }

    public void RemoveStock(int numberOfItems)
    {
        Items -= numberOfItems;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Given_A_Warehouse_With_20_Items
{
    private Order _order;
    private Mock<IWarehouseRepo> _warehouseRepo;
    private Warehouse _warehouse;

    [SetUp]
    public void When_An_Order_Is_Placed()
    {
        _warehouseRepo = new Mock<IWarehouseRepo>();
        _warehouseRepo.Setup(repo => repo.Load(It.IsAny<Warehouse>())).Callback<Warehouse>(warehouseArgument =>
            {
                warehouseArgument.Items = 20;
                _warehouse = warehouseArgument;
            }
        );

        _order = new Order(_warehouseRepo.Object);
        _order.AddOrderItems(5);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_The_Order_Now_Has_5_Items()
    {
        Assert.That(_order.Items, Is.EqualTo(5));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_The_Warehouse_Now_Has_15_Items()
    {
        Assert.That(_warehouse.Items, Is.EqualTo(15));
    }
}

public interface IWarehouseRepo
{
    void Load(Warehouse warehouse);
}
```

Comment: Is "No" a good answer? DI is the way to go here. Just ask for the test Warehouse and let the DI framework worry about how to load it from the repo.

Comment: @Paul, i understand No, fair enough, but I dont understanf your explanation. DI is not a cure all and there are constraints. I think my example doesnt expose the nub of the problem well enough.

Comment: @brumScouse, reading your update, I understand the stituation with being contrained with frameworks/classes you don't control. I still believe you can abstract that behind something you do control. In that class you can then new up and load the object by reference as intended. A nice rule of thumb with unit tests is that if it is difficult to settle on a test for a SUT that is a sign that you may need to refactor the design. The SUT is tightly coupled to something you have no control over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding public state to make testing easier is a valid technique when used correctly. Likewise living with complex tests, while letting the production code remain intact is also completely valid. Both can be wrong also, so a third option is to also look at your design. In reality which you chose depends on a variety of factors. Beware anyone who states the one true way.

## Public State

Adding public state is nice because it's easy, but poor because it wouldn't exist there if you weren't writing automated tests against the code. Usually this makes sense when you get hold of some legacy code and adding some additional fields isn't a big deal. If you make these read only you can limit the reach of these fields also. Interestingly in software this technique isn't used as much as it should be. In the field of hardware, circuitry and the like are physically shipped with testing components still attached. These are never used once shipped.

## Complex Tests

This tends to be the most common form you see. Messy or complex tests that do anything to get the tests to work. The nice thing here is at least the design isn't compromised with public fields just for the sake of testing, but the downside as you've noted is somewhat complex and ugly tests. You can offset this by using SUT builders or simply refactoring your tests as you go, such as extracting helpers to hide the messier parts. If you do this you can at least retain the benefits of clean code and cleaner tests.

## Look at the Design

Sadly the most underused but would have solved your problem. Tests hard to write? Then your design can do with improving. If the tests for new code requires public state to make it easy to test? Then your design can do with improving.

**Your Example**

In your case it makes sense to go with the lesser of two evils. The complex tests using the callback would be my personal recommendation. Simply when you weigh up the pros and cons of above. Yeah the test looks complex, and due to the tooling your using it has some rather gnarly syntax but it's not the end of the world.

If you really cannot change how you load the warehouse assuming either a 3rd party dependency or other reason there is another option. Create your own warehouse repository that would hide the command aspect and return a new warehouse instance. You would now have a query which you could then stub easily and side step the problems above. Sadly this would introduce a new component so you need to weigh this up. If you can change the component to become a query, I'd recommend that first.

The `Func` isn't really public state in my opinion. It's not a field. It's a rather novel hack around the fact the design is wrong.

Comment: Using composition is a good idea, I think that Nicos, given my edit, landed at a similar answer.  Yeah I can see the point about the additional component and you'd have to weigh up its benefit over using a Callback.   It was staring right at me wasn't it!

Answer (score 1):

How about neither. Bear with me as I walk through my thought process here. This looks more like an issue with design. I am reminded of an article I read recently about how *new is glue* in that Order should not couple itself with having to *new* up an instance of `Warehouse` or be responsible for exposing some way to configure it (SRP). I initially thought of adding a new dependency, something like a factory.

```
public interface IFactory<T> where T: class {
    T Create();
}
```

but then though against it as that would just be adding more gunk into the class. My thoughts were focused on avoiding the introduction of additional items into the SUT.

The thing is,...based on your example the SUT needed a way to be able to create a Warehouse and load it up but not be responsible for it while keeping it self relatively lean. Then I started thinking...Whose job/responsibility is it to manage Warehouse...

The **IWarehouseRepo** jumped out at me and then I remembered a pattern I saw in the Entity Framework's IDbSet.

```
public interface IWarehouseRepo {
    Warehouse Create();
    void Load(Warehouse warehouse);
}
```

Couldn't shake the feeling that I was overthinking the problem and ended up with something like this

```
//My job is to provide a loaded warehouse to those who want one.
public interface IWarehouseProvider {
    Warehouse GetWarehouse();
}
```

which would provide an already loaded Warehouse to be used by the order. Which is all it really wanted in the first place.

```
public class Order {
    private readonly IWarehouseProvider provider;

    public int Items { get; private set; }

    public Order(IWarehouseProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public void AddOrderItems(int numberOfItems) {
        //get a pre-loaded warehouse
        var warehouse = provider.GetWarehouse();
        warehouse.RemoveStock(numberOfItems);
        Items += numberOfItems;
    }
}
```

The order shouldn't care about creating or Loading a warehouse. It just wants a Warehouse to fulfill it's order. Why over complicate things. We had a good arrangement, now you want to get clingy. (I digress)

```
[TestFixture]
public class Given_A_Warehouse_With_20_Items
{
    private Order _order;
    private Mock<IWarehouseProvider> _warehouseProvider;
    private Warehouse _warehouse;

    [SetUp]
    public void When_An_Order_Is_Placed() {
        _warehouse = new Warehouse() { Items = 20 };
        _warehouseProvider = new Mock<IWarehouseProvider>();
        _warehouseProvider.Setup(provider => provider.GetWarehouse()).Returns(_warehouse);

        _order = new Order(_warehouseProvider.Object);
        _order.AddOrderItems(5);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_The_Order_Now_Has_5_Items() {
        Assert.That(_order.Items, Is.EqualTo(5));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_The_Warehouse_Now_Has_15_Items() {
        Assert.That(_warehouse.Items, Is.EqualTo(15));
    }
}
```

For me the thing that eventually lit the light bulb was you test. I decided to work backwards with what you were trying to test.

> Given A Warehouse With 20 Items

Sure the thought process may be flawed, but the Order class just wanted a loaded Warehouse and could care less about how it was created or loaded. I could be spinning top in mud as this still looks like the Factory pattern to me.

Edit. A potential provider can then look like this

```
public class DefaultWarehouseProvider : IWarehouseProvder {
    private readonly IWarehouseRepo repo;
    public DefaultWarehouseProvider(IWarehouseRepo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    public Warehouse GetWarehouse() {
        var warehouse = new Warehouse
        repo.Load(warehouse);
        return warehouse;
    }
}
```

Does this look like what you had before? Yes, yes it does. The thing now is that it is abstracted away into its own domain allowing its dependents to carry on with their tasks without concerns for how the sausage is made. You isolate/quarantine your constraints so that they don't go around spreading their code smell disease. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nkosi. I don't think I've exposed the problem enough I tried to fabricate something similar to the problem I have, but haven't quite hit the nail on the head.  If  I edit the answer to be a cut down exposition of what I actually have maybe it will be clear the problem I face and that I really only have those 2 options available to me given the confines of the framework I am using etc and with that, which one is actually the less of the 2 evils...

Comment: Stating "new is glue" is nice but far too simplistic. You can instantiate (new up) anything you want as long as the instance is not destructive. In other words (using DDD terminology) value types or entities can be new'd up all you want. There is no difference. Services on the other hand most likely want to be injected. So a hard and fast rule to avoid all "new's" is not right. If you do follow this advice everything becomes factories or builders that do nothing but hide a "new" and in turn ruin and complicate your code and design.

Comment: I was not saying to avoid all `new`. which is sometimes how people misunderstand the topic. I do understand and appreciate your view on the my response. Thanks.

Comment: Nkosi,  I think like Finglas you have come up with a real nice solution to the problem.  Like I said in the comment to Finglas this was just staring at me in the face!